# JS can't make eventlistener work

Tags: javascript, html, button, addeventlistener

can someone tell me what is wrong with this piece of code? i can't get it to work.
i'm trying to make this button clickable but its keep giving an error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

HTML:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="../CSS/Reset.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="../CSS/style.css" type="text/css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Psychic Game</title>

</head>
<body>
<script src="../JS/Javascript.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<button id="myBtn"> A </button>
<h1> Psychic Game </h1>

<h3> Guess what letter im thinking of </h3>

<h3> Wins: </h3>

<h3> Losses: </h3>

<h3> Guesses Left: </h3>

<h3> Your Guesses so far: </h3>
```

JS:

```
var computerChoice = letterBank[Math.floor(Math.random() * letterBank.length)];
function log() {
console.log(computerChoice);
}
//document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){console.log("computerChoice")});
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){console.log("computerChoice")});
```

Comment: change `#myBtn` to `"myBtn"` - `getElementById` expects a **string** as an argument, and it doesn't expect a CSS selector either

Comment: if i change that if says that "myBtn is not defined, but thank you

Comment: perhaps you don't have a button with `id="myBtn"` - or maybe your javascript is running before the button is created - as you haven't shown any other code, I'm only speculating

Comment: the button with that id does exist but thank you for the loading order ill check if thats the problem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some guidance on how to ask effective questions.  Specifically, please update your question with all code necessary to follow this.  That should include your HTML with #myBtn, and possibly a larger snippet of your JavaScript.  Finally, copy and paste the actual error message and stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move declaration of your script.js file below the actual DOM element you are referring to.

So your HTML should look like that:

```
<body>
<button id="myBtn"> A </button>
<script src="../JS/Javascript.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<h1> Psychic Game </h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

***Try It***

```js
document.getElementById('demo').addEventListener('click', function(){
  alert('clicked')
})
```

```html
<button type="button" id='demo'>Click Me!</button>
```

---

```js
document.getElementById('demo').addEventListener('click', function(){
  alert('clicked')
})
```

```html
<p id="demo">Click me</p>
```

---

Comment: i tried doing this but it still gave me this error:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at Javascript.js:16

Comment: Check this **link** [Link For your Problem](https://jsfiddle.net/abhishekpandey/nwganfLe/)

Answer (score 0):

You'd better study js first.
It should be:

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){console.log("computerChoice")});
```

Comment: i just copied and pasted this into it and it still gives me the same error

Comment: This isn't a particularly helpful response.  Describe specifically what you changed and why.  If you're going to answer, actually provide some knowledge.

Comment: @AlexanderKrikunov  u should push all ur code then. It's hard to find out the problem without more information.